# How to get WhatsApp contact detail?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to get detail info from WhatsApp like: status, last seen, picture, etc. when user enters a phone number.

Does WhatsApp provide any Messages Service API for Android or any solution?

Comment: Whatsapp  wont proved any API for accessing and you cant access status,last seen etc

Answer (score -2):

As of this writing, WhatsApp does [not offer](http://mashable.com/2015/03/25/whatsapp-developers-api/#_fSVZY0TESqT) API for developers. The best you can do (I know this does not answer your question) to integrate your app with WhatsApp is send a WhatsApp message from your app using [`intent`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).